# Sync a local directory with a remote directory in Linux

Tags: rsync, synchronization

I have a folder with a few files in it, and some space on a web server.  I want to do a bi-directional sync between the local folder and the remote one in linux, just on modification time.  How do I do this?  btw I cannot install anything on the server, for all intents and purposes it is just space.

Note:  I already have rsa key-pairs set up, so that it can happen silently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syncing directories in both directions with rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12197/syncing-directories-in-both-directions-with-rsync)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tool of choice for unidirectional synchronization is rsync, and the tool of choice for bidirectional synchronization is [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). Both require the executable to be available on both sides. If you can make a file executable on the server side, drop the unison binary and make it executable.

If you have Linux, *BSD, Solaris or Mac OS X locally, you can probably use a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem to make the web server space appear as a local filesystem — [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) should work since you seem to have ssh access. Then use unison “locally”.

Also note that most version control software (CVS/Subversion as well as distributed VCS) have synchronization as a by-the-way feature (check in on one machine and out on the other).

Answer (score 5):

If it's installed on the server, use `rsync` it's build for exactly that job.

To get it bi-directional do this (quote from http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626+1285799008594+28353475&threadId=1278777) :

To bidirectionally sync a directory `/src/foo` on `hostA` to `/dest/foo` on `hostB`,  including all the sub-directories, you would run these commands on  `hostA`:

```
rsync -auz /src/foo hostB:/dest 
rsync -auz hostB:/dest/foo /src
```

The first command pushes all the files that are newer on `hostA` to `hostB`.

The second command will pull all the files that are newer on `hostB` to `hostA`. The
critical options are:

when copying, you must preserve file modification times. `-a` does this and
other things;

If you want to preserve just the modification times, use `-t` instead.

To skip any files that are newer on the destination: `-u` does this.

Comment: as far as I've read rsync does not do bi directional and when I try to it gives me the error "protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?"

Comment: http://www.hostanswers.net/linux-hosting/rsync-protocol-version-mismatch/ might help you fix the version mismatch thing.

For the bi-directional thing I updated my answer.

Comment: Rsync is not adapted to bidirectional synchronization at all. For one thing it won't warn you if there is a conflict. Use Unison instead, it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: This does break horribly if server A is in the future from server B. In my case, I'm 13 hours ahead of the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you need a sync between two folders `rsync` is a great flexible choice. The Problem is, that rsync won't support the ftp protocol. A nice workaround for this is [curlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/):

> CurlFtpFS is a filesystem for accessing FTP hosts based on FUSE and libcurl.

With curlFtpFs pretty easy to include a remote ftp folder in your filesystem.

This is a short example which shows the usage of both tools:

```
curlftpfs -r -s ftp.foobar.com /foo
rsync -a /foo/ /bar
umount /foo
```

Read the manpage for further information.

If you don't want such effort to install curlFtpFS and just want to keep some files in sync, there are lots of ftp tools which offer such sync features:

- [FTPSync.pl](http://ossw.ibcl.at/FTPSync/) - simple PERL script to keep a local and a remote directory in sync
- [weex](http://weex.sourceforge.net/) - a non-interactive FTP client for updating web pages
- [filezilla](http://www.filezilla.de/) - GUI FTP client with lots of features
- ...

Comment: 1. Rsync is no good for *bidirectional* synchronization, use Unison instead. 2. Where did FTP come from? the mention of RSA keys in the question rather suggests ssh (and thus sshfs).

Comment: You are right, FTP is not mentioned in the question. To be honest I think it was a combination of "webspace" and "it is just space." and a bit of my fatigue yesterday.