# Syncing directories in both directions with rsync

Tags: rsync, synchronization

I happen to know about rsyn, and I use rsync to sync between my mac and a linux server as follows.

```
rsync -r -t -v MAC LINUX
rsync -r -t -v LINUX MAC
```

I expected to run the first command to sync, but I needed the second command also when a change is made in LINUX.

Am I missing something? Does rsync have an option to sync between two directories?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want bi-directional sync.  Take a look at unison, which does this: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

For example, on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install unison
$ unison MAC/ LINUX/
```

If you have trouble with permissions (example ext4 -> FAT):

```
$ unison -perms 0 vlc-2.2.0/ /media/sf_vlc/vlc
Contacting server...
Looking for changes
Reconciling changes

vlc-2.2.0      vlc                
new dir  ---->            /  [f] 

Proceed with propagating updates? [] y
Propagating updates
```

Comment: If you use `rsync` and the devices have the same filesystems, you can sync all permissions. `unison` does not support this use-case.

Answer (score 13):

It has been claimed that rsync was not recommended for two-way sync by its developers, but a source for this statement is lacking.

The already recommended unison utility will be a better solution for you.

Also keep in mind that you probably have to deal with a lot of Mac specific HFS+ stuff when using rsync. So be sure to use a properly patched rsync3 on the Mac or expect problems with modification dates (when using the Mac OS X provided rsync 2.6.9.)
If you don't know how to build a properly patched rsync 3 for the Mac, get mlbackup which includes just that. (Full disclosure: I am the author of mlbackup.)
Get it from github and be sure to download the full package from the downloads. (The mlbackup repo does not include rsync 3 which you want in this case.)
http://github.com/MacLemon/mlbackup

Comment: A link to the non-recommendation by rsync developers would be nice.

Comment: @Wildcard not from the developers, but [this](https://www.linuxpinguin.de/2010/10/bidirectional-rsync-flaws/) is relevant.

Comment: @Ploni that page makes very limited use of rsync's features. I would not take it as definitive in regard to bidirectional sync with rsync.

Comment: @MountainX you cannot use `rsync` for bidirectional synchronisation if you want to be able to propagate deletions either way

Comment: @roaima Why not? I'm testing it and it seems to be working. What am I missing?

Comment: Create a file. Synchronise. Delete the file. Synchronise. Watch it rise from the dead like a zombie

Comment: @roaima Maybe you aren't using the necessary rsync options. I am able to sync two ways without dead files rising like zombies (but only after I sorted out the required options).

Answer (score 5):

I coded this small tool for my own needs:

https://github.com/dooblem/bsync

It uses rsync and can handle file moves.

Comment: Thank you. I see you have committed a bug fix as recently as Mar 5, 2019. I will be giving your tool a try.

Answer (score 5):

You should also take a look at [csync](http://www.csync.org/), which is open source and offers native bi-directional syncing.

FYI - as far as I know - csync is developed by people from the Samba team. And knowing that the Samba team also developed rsync, I take this as a token of quality.

Comment: Works for me, https://csync.org/userguide/, but the tool itself was discontinued in 2013

Answer (score 2):

Another excellent tool for bidirectional sync.....[freefilesync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/)

Comment: on Stack Exchange, we prefer answers that are more than just links. it would be great if you could expand a little on what this is (what makes it different from `unison`?)

Comment: This project is a bit pushy in trying to get the users to make donations. Also, although source code is available. upstream does not host it on GitHub, GitLab or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Another system that provides for synchronization of directories in both directions is [SyncThing](https://syncthing.net/) ([Github](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing)) - "a continuous file synchronization program. It synchronizes files between two or more computers in real time, safely protected from prying eyes". There's also apps for mobile devices.