# bi-directional sync with rsync

Tags: rsync, synchronization

I am trying to setup bi-direction or two way sync with rsync. In my case I only need to delete the files when syncing from B to A. So, I was thinking of running rsync twice as follow :

```
rsync -rtuv ./A/ ./B/
rsync -rtuv --delete ./B/ ./A/
```

This problem with this solution is that when I run rsync (B->A) which would be right after running the rsync (A-B), Any new file that get created in between the sync will also get removed.

Is there a way I can specify a time stamp as condition that it only delete the file if it created before this date/time.

Updated:

I understand there is a unison solution but the problem with unison is required to install on both ends. I am syncing with a remote server and I can not install unison on the remote end.

Comment: There is a very similar question with some more answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936627/two-way-sync-with-rsync

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syncing directories in both directions with rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12197/syncing-directories-in-both-directions-with-rsync)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try osync which is designed for exactly this task.  I once set up a complex sequence of rsync commands to do the job, but I now use osync.

https://github.com/deajan/osync

It uses rsync internally, so it should be suitable for any situation where you could use rsync.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I was just about to answer my own question. I found very similar script called bsync (https://github.com/dooblem/bsync) basically it uses diff to figure out whats need to be sync. Since I am not expecting any conflicts in sync,  I also modify this script a little so it run silently when runs with a cron job.

Answer (score 16):

`rsync` is the wrong tool for this task, for exactly the reasons that you have encountered. Instead, consider using [`unison`](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison):

```
unison A/ B/
```

The first time you run this it will identify files that are uniquely in `A`, and those that are uniquely in `B`. It will also flag those that are in both places and ask you to identify which is to be overwritten.

The next time you run this it will copy changes from `A` to `B` and also `B` to `A`, flagging any files that have been changed in both places for manual resolution.

```
mkdir A B
date > A/date
who > B/who
unison A/ B/
# Lots of output from unison, showing synchronisation

ls A
date    who
ls B
date    who

date > A/date
unison A/ B/
# Lots of output from unison, showing synchronisation
```

There are a number of useful flags available for `unison` which help automate the process by defining assumptions and thereby reducing the number of questions you're asked during the synchronisation.

Comment: I saw unison solution but the problem with that is I am required to install on both end. I am syncing with a remote and I can not install unison on the remote end.

Comment: It doesn't help the OP, but I was looking for [unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).  I see there are [Debian packages](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/unison) and it supports ssh transport.

Comment: There are possibilities to use unison without installing it on the server, see the comments in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2936711 which points to http://i3vi3v.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/zend-studio-syncing-files-with-remote-server-using-unison/

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is [Rclone](https://rclone.org). Rclone is rsync for cloud storage (box,dropbox,nextcloud,ftp etc) and local storage.

Comment: How would they install *and use* rclone to solve their problem?

Comment: rclone doesn't have bidirectional sync yet.