# elegant way to sync file between local machine and server (in real time)

Tags: rsync, backup, webserver, synchronization

I am looking for a "local Dropbox" to sync files between local and server. For complex reason I couldn't install Dropbox on the server. I thought about [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org) but it doesn't work bi-directionally.

After researching a bit, my current solution is: having Dropbox running on local machine, and [rclone](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/) with some [assisting scripts](https://github.com/cjnaz/rclonesync-V2) deployed on the server. This is the best "local Dropbox" I could build without spending huge effort.

It works but with a bit high maintenance plus it crushes sometimes, so I'm looking for a simple and stable solution to sync file between local and server, **bi-directionally**. Consider speed and efficiency not a problem, 10X sync time compared with dropbox is acceptable (in LAN environment).

note: git is not an option as I would sync git repository and sometime media files between machines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bi-directional sync with rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256128/bi-directional-sync-with-rsync)

Comment: Take a look at syncthing.

Comment: It seems the connection stays in a LAN? You could use NFS or Samba in that case.